# Ordered caching based on object access rate

Tags: sorting, caching, 2d, coordinates

I have a system, that loads in polygonal "regions" based on virtual coordinates in a game. These lookups are quite expensive in terms of computing power, as it has to do the following:

- First it finds which quadrant of the coordinate system you're in
- It then loops through each region in that quadrant
- Each region consists out of smaller rectangles, so it then loops through all rectangles in the region, and check if the coordinates are within that region

The regions only account for 2D space, where the Z-value is ignored.

Anywho, so what I would need is something that would allow for faster lookups of often referred to regions, such as a formula that would order the regions based on the rate they get accessed, or something alike.

Or some other system that would allow for some sort of caching of the relation between coordinates and the region. (Not storing the coordinates and their respective region, however, as this would take up way too much memory)

Do you have any ideas for something that would help me achieve this?

Comment: It might be helpful to include some code, there are a lot of different ways this could be accomplished.

Comment: @JoshRumbut Don't know what code to post that would be relevant to this.  I mean, I can't just compress the whole thing into something easily readable without linking to the whole repo.